# Custom directive breaking code in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to add a custom directive to my code, but every time I add it, it breaks my code. I checked the console and is giving me the following error

```
Error: Argument 'guessGameController' is not a function, got undefined
at Error (native)
```

Now I am not sure if I am not setting my code right or if I am not adding the directive where is supposed to go. Here is my code, I appreciate all the help.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="guessGameApp">
<head>
    <title>Word Game 2.0 - AngularJS</title>
    <!--Encoding-->
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    <!--Scripts-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/maincontroller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--Styles-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/magicWord.css">
    <!--<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="guessGameController">
    <p>
        <header id="masthead">
            <h2 align="center">{{appTitle}}</h2>
        </header>
    </p>
    <div ng-controller="wordController">
        <p>
            <table align="center" width="300px" height="150px" border="solid 2px">
                <tr>
                    <td id="guessBox">
                        <p align="center">
                            <input value="" type="text" id="guestGuess" placeholder="Enter Guess" ng-model="guestGuess"/>
                        </p>
                        <p align="center"><button ng-click="addGuess()" id="guessButton">Click to Check</button></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3 align="center">Your guesses so far are: </h3>
                        <p align="center" ng-repeat="words in guesses">{{words}}</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p align="center">You have guessed:<b>{{guessed}}</b> times out {{allowed}} chances.</p>
                        <p align="center">You have <b>{{allowed - guessed}}</b> guesses left.</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                        <a custom-button>Click me</a>
                        <br />
                        <button custom-button>Hello</button>
                    </td>
               </tr>    
            </table>
        </p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var gameApp = angular.module('guessGameApp', []);
var gameTemplate = angular.module('guessGameApp', []);
```

maincontroller.js

```
gameApp.controller("guessGameController", function($scope)
    {
    $scope.appTitle = "WELCOME TO THE GUESS GAME!";
    });

gameApp.controller('wordController', function($scope)
    {
    $scope.guess = '';
    $scope.guesses = [];
    $scope.guessed= '';
    $scope.allowed = 6;
    $scope.wordToGuess = "Just";

    $scope.pushGuess = function () {
        $scope.guesses.push($scope.guestGuess);
        $scope.guessed = $scope.guesses.length;
        $scope.resetGuess();
    }

    $scope.resetGuess = function() {
        $scope.guestGuess = '';
    }

    $scope.addGuess = function()
        {
        if ($scope.guestGuess == null || $scope.guestGuess == '')
            {
                $("input[type=text]").ready(function () { $("#guestGuess").addClass("blur"); });
                $scope.result = "   Please enter a guess\n\nDon't leave the box empty.";
                alert($scope.result);
            }
        else if ($scope.guestGuess.toLowerCase() == $scope.wordToGuess.toLowerCase())
            {
                $("input[type=text]").ready(function () { $("#guestGuess").removeClass("blur"); });
                $scope.pushGuess(guestGuess);
                $scope.result = "You have guessed the correct word. Way to go!\n\n\t\t       The word was: ";
                alert($scope.result + $scope.wordToGuess);
            }
        else if ($scope.guestGuess != $scope.wordToGuess & ($scope.allowed - $scope.guessed) > 1)
            {
                $("input[type=text]").ready(function () { $("#guestGuess").removeClass("blur"); });
                $scope.pushGuess(guestGuess);
                $scope.result = "Please try again!";    
                alert($scope.result);
            }
        else if (($scope.allowed - $scope.guessed) <= 1)
            {
                $("input[type=text]").ready(function () { $("#guestGuess").addClass("doneBlur"); });
                $scope.guesses.push($scope.guestGuess);
                $scope.guessed = $scope.guesses.length;
                $scope.result = "Game over! The word was: ";    
                alert($scope.result + $scope.wordToGuess);
            }
        $scope.guess = '';
        }
    });
gameApp.directive('customButton', function () 
    { 
    $scope.wordToGuess = "Just";
    return { 
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: '../../templates/customTemplate.HTML',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs)
            {
            element.bind("click",function()
                {
                alert("The value of 'guessWord' is " + scope.wordToGuess);
                })
            }};
    });
```

customTemplate.html

```
<a href="" class="myawesomebutton" ng-transclude>
  <i class="icon-ok-sign"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: why are you creating two modules with the same name in app.js?

Answer (score 0):

In app.js remove the second module declaration

```
var gameApp = angular.module('guessGameApp', []);
//var gameTemplate = angular.module('guessGameApp', []); --> remove this line
```

You are also modifying DOM from the controller, this is not the angular way. If you want to add classes when some condition occurs, then have a look at `ng-class`

Comment: Sebastian, even after removing the second module my code directive is not working, I get the following error `Error: $scope is not defined`

Comment: where are you getting that? Verify that it is being injected correctly. In any case, your controller is being called now I suppose?

Comment: It is telling me that is in line 61 of my controller, this line is `replace: true,` which makes no sense. But yes my controller is being called now.

Comment: it is this probably `$scope.wordToGuess = "Just"` Scope is not defined at that stage, move that to the link function

Comment: Even there I still get another error `Error: Access to restricted URI denied`. There must be some error in my syntax. Thanks for the help.